# Can I create the active directory forest corp.domain.com without creating domain.com first?

Tags: active-directory

Is there any way which I can create the active directory domain `corp.domain.com` without first creating `domain.com` AD DCs?

Or to put another way, can corp.domain.com be the root of the forest?

Comment: (in response to the original version of the question) yes...it can...and don't.  -- http://serverfault.com/questions/76715/windows-ad-domain-naming-recommendations

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The FQDN of the forest root domain can be any valid FQDN, given that [its length does not exceed 65 characters](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/active-directory-maximum-limits-scalability(v=ws.10).aspx#BKMK_FQDN) and otherwise conforms to the conventions and limitations described in [KB909264](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/909264)

So **yes, it most certainly can** - just [don't use the `.local`-tld](https://serverfault.com/questions/76715/windows-ad-domain-naming-recommendations/473530#473530).

As noted in the comments, using an otherwise unused 3rd-level domain as the root of your AD DNS namespace is actually recommended, as you might otherwise end up with a naming collision when you want to use the 2nd-level name in public DNS and already have it in use internally.

Comment: OK thanks for the reply, so the emphasis is more on not using .local (in fact I will be uisng a .com that we own) so in summary `corp.mydomain.com` would perfectly fine without drawbacks?

Comment: Yes, and that's actually the recommended practice.