# Can not access the company web site

Tags: networking, windows-server-2008, web-server

Trust all you guys doing well today. I have a question.  My company website www.miracle-adventure.com cannot be accessed from within the company network.  I have a win2k8 R2 DC installed.  The domain is also miracle-adventure.com where server name is miracledc01.  Is there a way I can configure the users in the company network can access the company website.  The users can access other web sites without any issue....

Appreciate any assistance....

Comment: And that again proves why the [name of an AD domain](http://serverfault.com/questions/76715/windows-ad-domain-naming-recommendations/473530) shouldn't be set to your internet DNS domain name.

Comment: @HBruijn, Seriously? I never thought about that before... Thank you for pointing that out....do you have a "Solution"?

Comment: That link has actually quite a lot pointers about the hoops you have to jump through to make to deal with that bad design choice... Including: *This causes you to be forced to manually copy records from the Internet DNS (like `www`) into the Active Directory DNS zone to allow "external" names to resolve.*

Comment: @HBruijn, Tell me about it....& then You learn! :) Thanks again, I'll check

Comment: OK so all this are informative... How do I correct the issue presently I have at hand?

Answer (score 0):

Hi guys so I manage to access our company web site despite our AD been the same.  I Installed Web Server Role and That took care of it.  Now every one can go to the our web site wit ease... :)