# same DNS name internal and external server

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory, internal-dns

My internal domain name with the same name as the external domain.

when I'm tying to access to external domain from inside it is working properly with A record but my problem is the external IP changes everyday.

What is the easiest way to solve that issue ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

> My internal domain name with the same name as the external domain.

[That is an unfortunate choice...](https://serverfault.com/questions/76715/)

> my problem is the external IP changes everyday.

Upgrade your internet subscription from consumer grade to a (small) business contract with both a static ip-address and a real SLA.

Alternatively use [DynDNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_DNS) to update a hostname with the correct ip-address whenever yours changes and point a `CNAME`-record to that hostname instead of the `A`-record.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer... how is that possible to set "the correct ip address" if the IP changes almost every day.. ?