# Same Domain diffenrent NIC's - Windows Server 2012

Tags: windows

I have this senario in windows server 2012:
http://alojaimagens.com/viewer.php?file=1kx8421ra2c2rlc1ijqa.png

Both NICs have automatically the same DC domain! I don't want this as one is internal network and the other is connected to internet and I want to implement Direct Access.

Any sujestion is welcome :)
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, off topic - look to migrate away from .local (check [this Q&A](https://serverfault.com/questions/76715/windows-active-directory-naming-best-practices) for some good reasons) and use something like internal.example.tld

What are your DNS servers for the external interface and is it using DHCP? Both of these can set the domain "seen" by Windows.
Check your DHCP server for the external interface (if there is one) and check Option 135 - this sets the DNS search suffix.
Check it is pointing to either no DNS server (all lookups will be performed on the internal adapter's DNS) or an external one (such as your ISPs DNS, OpenDNS or GoogleDNS)