# Single *.company.com wildcard cert for RDS Deployment possible?

Tags: ssl-certificate, rds

With a Remote Desktop Services deployment in a domain `ad.company.com`, I have RDG and RDSH installed on the same server, `rd.ad.company.com`.

I can use a wildcard cert on `*.company.com` for access to the Gateway using the Remote Desktop Gateway Manager, and I can also make the rdp connection present this certificate to the client [following this guide](http://web.archive.org/web/20170627211650/http://www.msdonkey.com/server/install-and-configure-a-remote-desktop-certificate-on-rd-session-host-servers/).

[image]

If I try to connect from a remote client using `rd.company.com` as the gateway address and the server address, it fails even though I've added `rd.company.com` to the hosts file on the server.

If I try to connect using `rd.company.com` as the gateway and `rd.ad.company.com` as the server a certificate warning appears because `rd.ad.company.com` doesn't match the wildcard certificate `*.company.com` - I can connect but my aim is have no warning message.

Is it possible to cover both gateway and server with `*.company.com`, or will I need to get another cert for `rd.ad.company.com` or `*.ad.company.com`.

I don't want to use `company.com` as the domain instead of `ad.company.com`, because I understand that would [be a bad idea](https://serverfault.com/a/76721/83664).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done and it turns out it's not that difficult. You need to:

1. Makes sure `rd.company.com` points at the IP address of `rd.ad.company.com` *on the RDG* server. You can either add a new DNS zone for `rd.company.com` and add an empty A record pointing to the correct IP, or add an entry in the hosts file on the RDG. You could add the internal IP to your external DNS instead but I think that's a bit ugly.
2. Configure the RAP (Resource Authorization Policies) on the RDG using Remote Desktop Gateway Manager to allow `rd.company.com`. I did this by creating a new RD Gateway-Managed Group.

Now my rdp clients can connect with the standard RDP client software using `rd.company.com` as the address for both server and gateway, and the wildcard cert for *.company.com covers both.

Answer (score 1):

Wildcard certificates work for only one level of domains, that is, the most specific domain level.

So, you need to get another certificate for `*.ad.company.com`.

Comment: I know how wildcard certs work. So I can't make RDG act as gateway to `rd.company.com` to `rd.ad.company.com`? I'm asking if there is some way of aliasing in RDG I guess.

Comment: Unfortunately I know only how certificates work in the general use, I don't know about Remote Desktop.

Comment: Thanks Tero, I [figured it out](http://serverfault.com/a/708586/83664) :)