# SL7.1 (EL7.1) realm discover not discovering

Tags: redhat, sssd

Dabbling with joining an SciLinux 7.1 (EL7.1) box to an AD domain running on windows 2008R2 64bit.

Following the Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 Windows Integration Guide:

```
$ sudo realm discover -v mems.local
 * Resolving: _ldap._tcp.mems.local
 * Resolving: mems.local
 ! Discovery timed out after 15 seconds
mems.local
  type: kerberos
  realm-name: MEMS.LOCAL
  domain-name: mems.local
  configured: no
```

However:

```
$ nslookup -type=srv _ldap._tcp.mems.local
 Server:        172.17.21.20
 Address:   172.17.21.20#53

_ldap._tcp.mems.local   service = 0 100 389 mwinds2.mems.local.
_ldap._tcp.mems.local   service = 0 100 389 mwinds1.mems.local.
```

What do I do now?

```
# realm join mems.local
See: journalctl REALMD_OPERATION=r1063.5453
realm: Cannot join this realm

# journalctl REALMD_OPERATION=r1063.5453
-- Logs begin at Wed 2015-07-29 14:50:27 AKDT, end at Wed 2015-07-29 15:08:25 AKDT. --
Jul 29 15:08:10 playbox.mems.local realmd[5456]:  * Resolving: _ldap._tcp.mems.local
Jul 29 15:08:20 playbox.mems.local realmd[5456]:  * Resolving: mems.local
Jul 29 15:08:25 playbox.mems.local realmd[5456]:  * No results: mems.local

# nslookup _ldap._tcp.mems.local
Server:         172.17.21.20
Address:        172.17.21.20#53

*** Can't find _ldap._tcp.mems.local: No answer

# nslookup -type=srv _ldap._tcp.mems.local
Server:         172.17.21.20
Address:        172.17.21.20#53

_ldap._tcp.mems.local   service = 0 100 389 mwinds2.mems.local.
_ldap._tcp.mems.local   service = 0 100 389 mwinds1.mems.local.

$ tcping mwinds1 389
mwinds1 port 389 open.
```

Comment: Remember that [your domain should not be named with .local](http://serverfault.com/q/76715/126632)...

Answer (score 6):

Incase anyone stumbles upon this question, here's what fixed my Ubuntu 14.04 box where my domain name kept timing out.

Edit **/etc/nsswitch.conf:**

make the hosts line look like this -

```
hosts:          files dns mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] mdns4
```

Then try your discovery again.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using NetworkManager? IIRC what realm discover does is to query NM's D-Bus interface for the DHCP domain.

I would just try realm join mems.local directly, does that work?

Comment: no, network manager is not installed