# Internal network DNS can't be configed to route domain.com to www.domain.com?

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, active-directory

We host a domain on the internet that is accessible outside of our internal network using domain.com or www.domain.com, but is our actual internal network domain as well, but the external website is only accessible from our computers using www.domain.com - using domain.com gives "connection refused" in Chrome, and does a Bing search in IE.

I've asked our DNS guy about it, and he says internally domain.com goes to the internal network domain controller, and can't be rerouted/directed to the www version.

I've only done config on websites, not internal networks, so is there no way for domain.com from our internal network computers to resolve to www.domain.com?

Comment: I agree with him, as AD places `A` records for the domain controllers at the apex of the domain. This conflicts with the assumption made by web browsers that the `A` records should point at a webserver.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've fallen victim to a bad decision made by whoever set up your AD environment internally. More discussion here.

[Windows Active Directory naming best practices?](https://serverfault.com/questions/76715/windows-active-directory-naming-best-practices)

But the gist is that internally, your AD owns the name `example.com` in DNS. That name will always and forever (unless you rename the domain) point to your domain controllers. So the only way to redirect web requests to your actual web servers is to run a web server on every domain controller that is configured to do the redirect.