# Any reason to use ".0" tld?

Tags: routing, domain, internet, intranet, local

We have some servers, which are currently only accessible from our internal network. They are named "redmine.0" and so on, and our internal DNS server resolves the IP addresses.

But I wonder if there is any reason at all to use a ".0" tld instead of just using our "mycompany.com" domain. In the future it may be necessary to enable access to the server from the internet, and this would be easy if the name is already "redmine.mycompany.com".

On the other hand, we will probably use a reverse proxy in front, which could forward the requests to "redmine.0". But then we would also need to route internal traffic in some way...

Is there any "best practice" for those scenarios? Just to be clear, we do not have any AD, so I am talking about "normal DNS".

Comment: Best practice is fully qualified domain names everywhere, using only domains you control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although using a number for a internal only TLD is relatively safe, it will at least not conflict with publicly registered domain names as [RFC 3696](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3696) confirms that no number only TLD's will be found online, it is not best practice.

Best practice to **use an actual domain that you fully control**, even when it is for internal-only use. That can either be a dedicated domain for internal use or a subdomain of the domain name you use on the internet. The arguments in the [canonical Q&A on Active Directory domain names](https://serverfault.com/q/76715/37681) hold true in that regard as well.