# Domain Controller DNS settings for root domain

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory, intranet

So as the company growing, we are recently moving all intranet workstations onto a windows domain for better management.

Our web server is inside our company network but we have public DNS records pointing our domain to our Internet addresss, say
1.1.1.1 example.com
1.1.1.1 www.example.com

Therefore all Intranet and Internet users are used to be able to access our website through either example.com and www.example.com - these two behaves exactly the same.

Now that we're in domain, I have deployed a DNS/DC computer with Windows 2012 R2 with such DNS record:
192.168.1.10 example.com

However this breaks connection for the intranet users who wants to access our website with URL such as: https://example.com/homepage

Users from the Internet can still use either www.example.com or example.com while this convenience is not enjoyed by intranet users.

I can of course require all intranet users to use full name like https://www.example.com/homepage

However I am sort of a perfectionist (or fussy) who wants to have the cake and eat it too. Besides we might have hard-coded some of these URL in codes I am not immediately aware of that are now broken due to usage of example.com.

I don't know about the best practice when settings the DNS records. Maybe I should not use root domain for the AD domain and should use some child domain like intranet.example.com? But then wouldn't it be a problem if one day we decide to deploy exchange server and stuff?

I have found some AD management articles, which are not very helpful on this matter. Could someone shed some light on it?

Comment: https://serverfault.com/q/76715/37681

Comment: Good read. Thanks for pointing me to the right direction