# Bind9 .local stub zone

Tags: bind, internal-dns, mdns

I have a Windows 2012R2 Windows AD domain "example.local" that I need to to setup a stub (preferable) or a conditional forwarder but my named fails to locate or resolve a remote ".local" domain.  The masters are reachable and I can nslookup/dig to them directly.  Other stubs that are not a .local resolve correctly but I am guessing the mDNS warning from dig is my issue and I haven't found a way around this.

```
zone "example.local" {
    type stub;
    masters { 192.168.0.5; 192.168.0.6; };
```

```
$ nslookup server1.example.local

Server:     127.0.0.1
Address:    127.0.0.1#53
** server can't find server1.example.local: SERVFAIL
```

```
$ dig server1.example.local
; <<>> DiG 9.11.13-RedHat-9.11.13-6.el8_2.1 <<>> server1.example.local
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; WARNING: .local is reserved for Multicast DNS
;; You are currently testing what happens when an mDNS query is leaked to DNS
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: SERVFAIL, id: 14164
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
; COOKIE: 98c1d3e8a0e6bad5286641e85faaa9c39bb8927923b46b3a (good)
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;server1.example.local.     IN  A

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1)
;; WHEN: Tue Nov 10 09:54:59 EST 2020
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 77
```

Comment: The root is probably that you chose the "wrong" name for your AD domain https://serverfault.com/q/76715/546643

Comment: Not my choosing but, unfortunately for me, this is my problem now.

Comment: You specifically want to stay away from `.local` TLD as this is used by mDNS.

Comment: Many are stuck with `.local` AD domains, because someone else has chosen them many years ago. Can't blame them, either, because Microsoft has actually recommended this back then. Because this isn't about chosing the AD domain for a fresh installation and it's laborious and sometimes impossible to change it, your comments aren't helpful at all, despite you are right.

Comment: Just wondering, why a stub and not a conditional forwarder? When you reload BIND, do you see anything in the logs regarding the new stub zone?