# Can not access company website from within LAN domain

Tags: active-directory, domain, internal-dns

This is probably something simple but I'm having a brain fart trying to sort this out.

I'm trying to mimic an existing physical location setup by a previous engineer.

I've set up a new physical site [Site 2], I've setup a new domain controller/DNS [example2.uk] this matches the company website [Example2.uk], all the site computers can join the domain and work as expected, the only issue I'm coming across I cannot access the company website hosted with WIX protected though Cloudflare.

Any advise would be appreciated

Comment: Maybe there is a typo there... is your AD domain name the same as your Internet domain name? Because you wrote "example2.uk" and "example2.com". This should not create any issue. If instead you are using the same domain name for both, then you *will* have issues.

Comment: My apologies yes a typo..... My ADDomain & website are Example2.uk

Comment: Some background as to why that is considered a sub optimal choice : https://serverfault.com/questions/76715/windows-active-directory-naming-best-practices

Answer (score 1):

You should not use the same domain name for your public Internet domain and your Active Directory domain.

When you create an Active Directory domain, your Domain Controllers become DNS servers for a zone with the same name as your AD domain (in your case, "example2.uk"); this means they'll become authoritative for this DNS zone, thus they will never query public Internet DNS servers for its contents; they will just answer any query with what *they* know about the zone. This is called "[split-horizon DNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split-horizon_DNS)".

In this scenario, if you want to resolve public names such as "www.example2.uk" or "mail.example2.uk" from inside your network, you will need to manually create records in your internal DNS zone and have them point to the real servers hosting the services; this causes some management overhead, but it can be done... *except* for the root of the zone.

In an Active Directory domain, the name of the domain (such as "example2.uk") must be mapped to Domain Controllers; this is automatically managed by DCs: each DC will automatically register an empty A record pointing to its IP address. If you look at the DNS zone in your environment, you'll easily notice those records.

This means **you can't map the name of the domain to the IP address of a web server**.

Comment: To nitpick: you *can* work around this issue by running your web server on your Domain Controller(s). But it should be obvious why this would be *a very bad idea*.