# Windows AD Domain named like an existing website

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, domain-name-system, active-directory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sharing Domain name between domain controller and webserver](https://serverfault.com/questions/38208/sharing-domain-name-between-domain-controller-and-webserver)

I have run into an issue similar to:

[Windows Active Directory naming best practices?](https://serverfault.com/questions/76715/windows-ad-domain-naming-recommendations)

Our domain was created as corp.com, but we use the DNS domain corp.com (for our website, for instance). To add insult to the injury, our www.corp.com tends to redirect to corp.com (lots of links point to corp.com, etc.).

Can I make corp.com resolve to our hosting's IP without creating problems? If so, how?

What's the proper thing to do?

Comment: Please see this question, which asks the same thing:
http://serverfault.com/questions/38208/sharing-domain-name-between-domain-controller-and-webserver

Answer (score 0):

The 'proper' thing to do is to fix the web site so it doesn't have links pointing to corp.com.

If you do this correctly, it works fine. For example, my network is all real IP addresses, and has an AD domain of corp.com . www.corp.com resolves in DNS to the IP address of the web server.

If this doesn't appeal, 2008 server allows renaming ADs, which may be the least painful way to proceed.